# How to get the text value from a textarea from a web browser control in C#

Tags: c#

How can I get the text value from a textarea from a web browser control in C#. If I don't know the ID or the Name of the textarea?

```
  var element1 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea");
  foreach (HtmlElement el in element1) {
    //GET THE TEXT
  }
```

EDIT: `<textarea name="message"></textarea>`

How would I get the value?

Comment: Can you not specify the name/id to simplify this process? Edit: Why can't you specify the name/id?

Comment: have you check the el.InnerHTML property?

Comment: @AGoodDisplayName the name="message"

How would I get the text?

Comment: -1 This question is missing too much information for us to help you effectively. Please specify whether this is an app that interacts with a web browser or a web-app which processes users' requests. Also, you first say "I don't know the ID or the Name", then you edited your question to include `<textarea name="message">` ... do you have a name on the HTML element or not?

Comment: Also, what type is the `webBrowser1` variable?

Comment: After Jesse Webb's last comment it made me realize that you may be trying to access a textarea that did not come from your code through the WebBrowswer control through possibly a webform/wpf control? If that's the case...my below answer will not work. I thought you were using asp.net and I'll delete it.

Comment: @JesseWebb Its a WEB BROWSER control.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
varelement1= Request.Form["textarea"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done entirely using LINQ but you could have an extension defined like this

```
static class ControlExtension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(this Control parent)
        {
            foreach (Control control in parent.Controls)
            {
                yield return control;
                foreach (Control descendant in control.GetAllControls())
                {
                    yield return descendant;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and call

```
var list = this.GetAllControls().OfType<TextArea>().ToList();
```